# Swift: placeholder in UiSearchBar appearing only after typing something and then backspacing

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, placeholder, uisearchcontroller

In my iOS app (Swift/XCode 6.4) I have a table view controller with a UISearchController containing a search bar with a scope bar. I would like that when a certain scope button is pressed then a placeholder appears. This is what I did:

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    self.filteredTasks.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

    switch (self.resultSearchController.searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex) {
      ...
      case 3:
          self.resultSearchController.searchBar.placeholder = "dd/mm/aaaa"
          ...
}
```

where resultSearchController is a property of my view controller Swift class:

```
var resultSearchController = UISearchController()
```

The strange thing is that the placeholder appears only if, after selecting that scope button, I type something and then I backspace erasing what I had typed...
Why this?

Comment: don't you have a white space or something? check with the attribute inspector

Comment: I would say no...I didn't even touch that

Comment: You should just manually clear all spaces when search bar ends editing and manually set placeholder again

Comment: @MSU_Bulldog: but the placeholder doesn't show even before start editing...

Comment: If you are using Interface Builder, there is a placeholder property

Comment: I did not use Interface Builder to add a UISearchController(). I added it by code because of iOS 8...many people told me that interface builder still does not support it